# making array unique with only one value same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array of kind

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [username] => test1
        [case1] => abc
        [case2] => zxc
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [username] => test1
        [case1] => fdg
        [case2] => tyy
    )

)
```

As you can see only id and username is same rest are different. Now i want to make it unique. That if only id is same in inner arrays then also only one value should come either of both.

Can any one tell me how to do this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the unique data as keys makes this easy:

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $unique[$item['id']] = $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new array in which to `push` the inner arrays if there is no duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Use this for finding & removing specific unique in array [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#105169)

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'id', as key for your top array (or 'username'?).